# Is there a way to bulk convert aspx pages to pdf?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf

Adobe Acrobat doesn't support converting aspx files (only html), and the SPFx solution (react-command-convert-to-pdf) doesn't either. The tools I can use are Adobe CC, power automate but don't have a paid converter.

Comment: For anyone else who comes here to find an answer, the Muhimbi connector in one of the comments 'works' but it is limited. (I can't reply to that post due to my 'reputation score'). I worked with a Muhimbi Tech and found if the converted PDF spans multiple pages, it won't automatically convert them. You have to play with a property within the connector (Viewport Size) and it's VERY specific to the individual aspx page. That means you 'may' have to set that property for **each page** you want to convert. That doesn't allow for for much flexibility or automation unless your ASPX pages are consist

Answer (score 0):

Here is a article about Converting Modern SharePoint Online Pages (ASPX pages) to PDF with Muhimbi PDF Converter Services Online and Power Automate flow.

For Reference: [Converting Modern SharePoint Online Pages (ASPX pages) to PDF](https://kamdaryash.wordpress.com/2020/08/12/converting-modern-sharepoint-online-pages-aspx-pages-to-pdf/)

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.